# How do I identify constituents and clause boundaries?

Tags: grammar, syntax-trees, clauses, constituents

I'm going through some practice exercises for an upcoming exam and trying to do syntax trees is really tripping me up. Could anyone please walk me through how they would break them down and how to apply the relevant constituency tests? I don't think I'm doing it correctly at all right now!

> I gifted her a fortune that others would sell their souls for.

Here's how I've broken this one down.

[image]

I'm not sure how to segment the NP regarding what is gifted, or how the conjunction [that] fits into it. Also, the preposition [for] at the end doesn't seem right.

> Do you think I should braid the girl's hair for her?

None of the ways I've attempted to diagram this one make any sense.

> Why you said that, I will never understand.

I know how to diagram the [I will never understand] clause on its own, but I can't figure out how the rest fits in when structured as a preposed theme.

> Tell my wife I will do something unforgivable to them if they do not stop.

Again, the conjunction [if] is confusing me, and identifying the boundaries of the NP(s) in the latter half of the sentence.

Comment: You may want to specify what framework you’re supposed to use in the trees (looks like maybe Syntactic Structures method) since there are many others (like X Bar).

Comment: What Graham said. Or tell us if you have a core textbook that you're using?

Comment: For example, what theory has NP branching to N Conj VP; what theory has VP branching to NP Aux VP P?

Comment: "others ... souls for" is a clause, not a VP. The "for" is part of the VP "sell their souls for".

Comment: @Sam Why don't you assign function labels (subj, modifier etc.) to every constituent?

Comment: Chapter 3 of McCawley 1998 is about tests for constituency. How you decide where a clause ends is something you should discuss with your confessor.